# How can I switch between my Nvidia and Intel HD graphics to save battery life?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, power-management, battery

My laptop use to run on Windows 8 but then I decided I wanted to switch to ubuntu, but the fans are always extremely loud from just browsing the web AND my battery life estimate is 1:30 Minutes!!! I assume this is because it is using nvidia graphics, but i need to maximize my pc's battery life and make it use intel.

Specs:

```
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970M 6GB
Intel Core i7-6700HQ 2.6GHz
16GB DDR4
1920x1080
```

Comment: Have you checked your computers BIOS firmware version at the manufacturers web site? How about the Nvidia software and firmware? Do you know how to edit /etc/default/grub and update grub? Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1):

Your fans should not be running at full speed unless the processors get hot. For example type the following in the terminal (do not enter the `$` this represents the terminal prompt):

```
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp
80000
80000
78000
```

There are three thermal zones on my laptop (Intel Core i-7 3630QM) and although at 80C the fan can hardly be heard.

Check if Intel Turbo mode is turned on:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
0
```

Zero means turbo is turned on. To save a bit of power you can turn off Intel Turbo Boost with:

```
$ echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

Your CPU can have various power saving plans (CPU governors) at your disposal. For example mine has:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors
performance powersave
performance powersave
performance powersave
performance powersave
performance powersave
performance powersave
performance powersave
performance powersave
```

A quad core i-7 actually has 8 CPU's as you can see and each CPU can have it's own power plan.

To see the power plan of CPU0 we would use:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
powersave
```

In your case though, I would consider upgrading Intel Microcode through `System Settings`,`Software & Updates`, `Additional Drivers`. Also upgrading Kernel to 4.7.3 (which I've tested for weeks) or 4.7.5 (which I just started using tonight). First though I would google your processor and "fan runs at full speed" for possible bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

The most dependable way is the Prime switcher in program "nvidia-settings". You choose nvidia or onboard then log out and log back in again. Does not automatically switch speeds when needed, you are just swapping out copies of /etc/X11/xorg.conf, so far as I can tell.

I expect you will not mind switchin to on board graphics. On Dell Precision 5501, I notice no benefit from Nvidia card, except avoiding the flaws of the Intel graphics driver that infested ubuntu 16.04lts in the beginning. Updates seem to have solved those.

There is a linux project for automatic switching, attempt to support Nvidia Optimus. I tested it, could not make it work. Called BumbleBee. If you make that work, I'd like to hear more.